# Bootstrap cards are overlapping when I am using for loop in Django

Tags: python, django

I am facing issue in displaying Bootstrap cards. Cards are overlapping when I am using for loop in Django. Can anyone please help?

Here is the code:

[image]

Comment: Please use code instead of a image.

Comment: maybe a problem with the location of {% for and {% endfor tag. {%for is before all div tag but {% enfor is not after the closing div tag